# I need to do specific 301s as well as wild card/catch all. How do I do it?

Tags: .htaccess, wildcard, http-status-code-301

Regarding .htaccess:

I've got a site I'm closing down. It's got thousands of urls, most dynamic, that does not translate well to my new site, as the structure is completely different.

My .htaccess has about two hundred (the most important ones) URLs 301'ed (manually) to my new site. This I want to follow with a rule that sends every other url, except the ones I did manually, to the landing page of my new site. I cannot get anything to work, as the catchall i've tried ignore the manual 301s.

Can anyone kindly help me out with a rule?

Best regards, 
SK

Comment: Certainly no one can help if you do not paste your rewrite rules (the .htaccess file).

Comment: You're right of course. Here's what it looks like currently:  Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,L]
Redirect 301 /this.html  http://www.example.com/something/somethingelse/that.html   There's a ton of similar 301's after this first one.

Comment: Sorry, can't make it display right. Anyway, there's a http:// and a www in front of the second url in the 301 line.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, your additional comments don't really make clear what you have so far. I guess this might be the idea which looks good to me if placed in this order:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule /this.html http://www.example.com/something/somethingelse/that.html [r=301,L] 
[...299 more static rules...]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,L]
```

That should actually work. 
If not it usually is a good idea to switch on rewrite logging and raise the log level. ('RewriteLog' and 'RewriteLogLevel' commands). This gives you tons of information into a separate log file. Usually it helps a lot to understand what is going on.

And, instead of coding 300 static rules you might save time using the RewriteMap command.